# Condition Alert with NgFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to achieve a popup if i get a null on my ngfor

```
    <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selectedKidId">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let kid of kids" [value]="kid.id">{{kid.name}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

This will show me a list of kids name, i want to get a pop up if there is no kid on the list. is there a way to do it ?

Thank you

kids.ts

```
export class KidsPage {
  selectedKidId: string
  kids: Kid[] = []
  loveAmount: number

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private kidProvider: kidProvider,
  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.initKids()
  }

  initkids() {
    this.kidProvider.getkid().subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        this.kids = data['mykids']
        if (this.kids.length > 0) {
          this.selectedKidId= this.kids[0].id
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(`getKids failed: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      })
    this.kidProvider.subscribeToKids()
  }
```

Comment: `*ngIf(kids.length === 0) ...` Do you want an actual `alert` or to display something different in your HTML?

Comment: or `*ngIf(!kids)` if it can be `null`

Comment: @bugs i want to display a model if possible.

Comment: @Taieb what model? Or do you mean a *modal*? (I.e. [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview))

Comment: @bugs yes sorry modal, like this one https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Comment: @Taieb.. Can you please post the code of your component class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write `Dialog` open code when there is no data in your array like this

```
initkids() {
    this.kidProvider.getkid().subscribe(
      ({ data }) => {
        this.kids = data['mykids']
        if (this.kids.length > 0) {
          this.selectedKidId= this.kids[0].id
        } else {
             // ----Open your modal instead -----
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(`getKids failed: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      })
    this.kidProvider.subscribeToKids()
  }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much That's it.